# Admin on rest - How to use DependentInput with ReferenceInput

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

For example, I have two endpoints:

/level/

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": 1
    "field": 2
}
```

/level_type/

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "value": "test1"
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "value": "test2"
}
```

I created  component:

```js
    export const LevelEdit = (props) => {
        return <Edit {...props}>
            <SimpleForm>
                <ReferenceInput source="type" reference="level_type">
                    <SelectInput optionText="value"/>
                </ReferenceInput>

                <DependentInput dependsOn="type.value" value="type2">
                    <NumberInput source="field"/>
                </DependentInput>
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    };
```

I want that NumberInput depends on a nested field (from ReferenceInput). NumberInput will appear if I select level_type.id = 2 where value = "type2".

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you ever figured out the answer?